# How to parse json array in vb.net?

Tags: .net, arrays, json, vb.net, parsing

I am learning about **JSON** and I want to parse json array and get only one value using **VB.Net**. I found this [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229563/vba-getting-values-from-a-collection) with answers but *I didn't seem to get what I was looking for*. According the the questioner, he has this

```
"links":[
  {
    "rel":"next",
    "href":"www.google.com"
  }
]
```

and we can use this to parse json array

```
   links(1).Item("rel")
```

or this

```
links(1)("rel")
```

What if I only have this?

```
[{
    "rel":"next",
    "href":"www.google.com"
}]
```

How should I code it without the word **links**? I understand that *links* is the table name, isn't it? I tried so many possibilities which give me more errors. I'd appreciate much if anyone can help me out.

*P.S. This not a duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18076744/how-to-parse-json-list-in-vb-net-newtonsoft) because I am not going to add the information to a DataGridView. What I want here is to parse a field. Get only one result and not the entire list.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Parse Json list in VB.NET Newtonsoft](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18076744/how-to-parse-json-list-in-vb-net-newtonsoft)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

found this that can parse **json** providing this [library](https://json.codeplex.com/) is installed.

```
        Dim token As JToken
        Dim rel
        Dim href
        For Each value As Object In result
            token = JObject.Parse(value.ToString())
            rel = token.SelectToken("rel")
            href = token.SelectToken("href")

            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", rel, href)
        Next value
```

providing that this code is present

```
' Create a request for the URL. 
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://")

        ' If required by the server, set the credentials.
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        ' Get the response.
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        ' Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
        ' Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        ' Read the content.
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        'Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)
        Dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of ArrayList)(responseFromServer)
```

and this code at the *bottom*

```
        Console.ReadKey()
        ' Clean up the streams and the response.
        reader.Close()
        response.Close()
```

with imports...

```
        Imports System
        Imports System.IO
        Imports System.Net
        Imports System.Text
        Imports Newtonsoft.Json
        Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
```

found it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [this](https://adevelopersnotes.wordpress.com/2013/11/10/parsing-json-to-key-value-pairs-with-json-net/) is a code in c# form that i found... for reference only.

Answer (score 6):

You need to do use :

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of <Your Class object>)(<JSON String>)
```

go through with this link [Deserialize Json](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-us/5aff70d4-8d43-4305-b562-e15155dfc7cd/deserialize-json-with-vbnet)