# Output JSON Nested Array to VB.net Object

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net

I am de-serializing a JSON string  that has a nested array to a vb.net object.  The JSON is valid and I can de-serialize most of it.  However, I am not clear if my class properties are written correctly to accomplish this with a nested array.  I am also getting an odd error, noting "Value of type char cannot be converted to clsJson.datum," when no char type is present anywhere (that I can see!).

my classes:

```
Public Class clsJson
Public Property latitude As Double
Public Property minutely As Minly  
End Class

Public Class Minly                           
Public Property summary As String
Public Property icon As String
'***Public data As Datum()
Public Property data() As List(Of Datum)
End Class

Public Class Datum
Public Property time As Integer
Public Property summary As String
Public Property icon As String
Public Property precipIntensity As Double
Public Property precipProbability As Double
End Class
```

My code:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class test_1a

Dim strJsontxt As String = Nothing
Dim myWeather As clsJson

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        '***** paste strJson to textbox; final will download from web
        strJsontxt = TextBox3.Text
        txtInput.Text = strJsontxt

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

    Try
        myWeather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of clsJson)(strJsontxt) 'works            
        Console.WriteLine("Latitude:  " & myWeather.latitude) *'works*                        
        Console.WriteLine("Minutely_Summary:  " & myWeather.minutely.summary) *'works* 

        Console.WriteLine(myWeather.minutely.data)  *'returns*      ‘System.Collections.Generic.List`1[JSON_2.Datum]

        For Each data As Datum In strJsontxt  '*Error:* "Value of type char cannot be converted to clsJson.datum”
            Console.WriteLine("Min_data.toString:  " & myWeather.minutely.data.time)
        Next

        debugOutput(txtInput.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        debugOutput(txtInput.Text)
    End Try

End Sub

End Class
```

My JSON (validated- OK):

```
{
"Latitude": 26.422518,
"Longitude" :  80.147245,
"minutely": {
"summary": "Partly cloudy for the hour.",
"icon": "partly-cloudy-day",
"data": [
  {
    "time": 1503329280,
    "precipIntensity": 0,
    "precipProbability": 0
  },
  {
    "time": 1503329340,
    "precipIntensity": 0,
    "precipProbability": 0
  },
  {
    "time": 1503329400,
    "precipIntensity": 0,
    "precipProbability": 0
  }
 ]
 }
 }
```

The Problems:

1. The output of:
   Console.WriteLine(myWeather.minutely.data)  'returns                ‘System.Collections.Generic.List`1[JSON_2.Datum]

and

2. My For Each loop, where i want to read the minutely.data array shows this error:  Error "Value of type char cannot be converted to clsJson.datum”

I am sure I have something out of order or missing in my clsJson.  Can anyone offer any help.  I have researched this pretty well.  There is something similar at [How to parse json array in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161949/how-to-parse-json-array-in-vb-net) , but not quite there.  Thanks!!

Comment: `myWeather.minutely.data` is an array (or list) so thats why you see the data type.  Access the memebrs to get at the data: `myWeather.minutely.data(index)` where index is a number 0 to however many there are

Comment: @Plutonix:  I am getting closer, but I still am not pointing to the data(index) correctly:

Comment: @Plutonix:  I am getting closer, but I still am not pointing to the data(index) correctly:  ` For Each i As Datum In New List(Of Datum)
                Console.WriteLine("Line: time:   " & i.time)
            Next  `     I get no Intellisense error and i has the appropriate properties,  but no output.  What am I missing?

Comment: If you are deserializing, *you* dont create that list.  Hold your mouse over the `myWeather` object.  You have 1 or 2 properties missing, but the list/array should be filled

Comment: Hooray!!!  For Each Item As Datum In myWeather.minutely.data
                Console.WriteLine("PrecIpIntensity: Expect a 0 here:   " & Item.precipIntensity)
                Console.WriteLine("Expect: unix date 150341220 with each item increase 60 min:  " & Item.time)
            Next           Thank you, @Plutonix !!